# Working on list of data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I have a list made up of some data.tables that are all of the same exact structure

```
dt1 <- data.table(A=1:10, B=letters[1:10], C=rnorm(10))
dt2 <- data.table(A=1:10, B=letters[11:20], C=rnorm(10))
dt3 <- data.table(A=1:10, B=letters[15:24], C=rnorm(10))
dt.list <- list(dt1,dt2,dt3)
```

How can I use the special subsetting syntax/power of data.table on each data.table element in the list at once? For example do this `dt[, sum(A), by=B]` to each data.table in `dt.list`?

I thought something like this `lapply(dt.list, '[', (,sum(A), by=B))` might work because this works: `lapply(dt.list, '[', A==5)` but alas, it does not.

I would like to save the result as a new list of data.tables. Also interested to know how I can incorporate `:=` as well. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The correct way, in my opinion, is `DT = rbindlist(dt.list, idcol=TRUE); DT[, sum(A), by=.(.id, B)]`. There is rarely any good reason to maintain a list of separate tables. The efficiencies in computation and syntax that data.tables have for by-group operations (including taking `sum()`) are probably greater when using a single table.

Comment: If you really need to apply the function separately, use anonymous function call i.e. `lapply(dt.list, function(x) x[, sum(A), by = B])`